# Changing background colour of header in bootstrap file

Tags: css, asp.net

Following is the code in my bootstrap file. I have tried to change the border      colour with all my skills but I was unable.

These are the names of my classes and within the brackets the colour is written

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-form {
  border-color: #101010;
}
```

[image: Code image]

Answer (score 1):

**Use This:**

```
.navbar{
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Comment: Next time when you post a question make sure that code is seperated from the description of the question.And also if answer works for you please mark it worked by clicking up-arrow button beside the answer,so that others don't need to look this question instead they can answer other questions :-)